How to append form value to google sheet starting from second column in web apps script?
Index.html
There are five input option in the html form
<form id="collegeInfo" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit()">
  <div class="mb-1">
    <div class="form-group col">
      <label for="districtName" class="form-label">Please Select District of the Institution</label>
      <select class="form-select form-select-sm" id="districtName" name="districtName" required>
          <option>--Select District--</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

<div class="mb-1">
    <div class="form-group col">
      <label for="upazilaName" class="form-label">Please Select Upazila of the Institution</label>
      <select class="form-select form-select-sm" id="upazilaName" name="upazilaName" required>
          <option>--Select Upazila--</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="mb-1">
    <label for="name" class="form-label">Enter the full name of the Institution:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control form-control-sm" required>
  </div>

<div class="mb-1">
    <label for="email" class="form-label">Enter E-mail of the Institution:</label>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="form-control form-control-sm" required>
  </div>

<div class="mb-1">
    <label for="eiin" class="form-label">Enter EIIN of the Institution:</label>
    <input type="number" id="eiin" name="eiin" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Enter English Digits only"  required>
  </div>

  <button id="collegeInfo-submit-btn" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>

JavaScript
  function handleFormSubmit() {
    var formData = readFormData();

          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(disAlertMsg).processFormCreate(formData);
function disAlertMsg(){
 Swal.fire({
          position: 'center',
          icon: 'success',
          title: 'Submitted Successfully',
          showConfirmButton: true,
          timer: 1500
          })
}        
document.getElementById("collegeInfo").reset();
  }

function readFormData() {
    var formData = {};
    formData["districtName"] = document.getElementById("districtName").value;
    formData["upazilaName"] = document.getElementById("upazilaName").value;
    formData["name"] = document.getElementById("name").value;
    formData["email"] = document.getElementById("email").value;
    formData["eiin"] = document.getElementById("eiin").value;
    return formData;
}


Code.gs
I am trying to append html form value into google sheet starting from second Column (B Column) using Sheet api, but can't success
const SPREADSHEETID = "11uGKfy0Jh-24-RI-iIdjGhDtWxwhgiKRHT8JS9guP-Q";
const DATARANGE = "Form responses 1!B2:F";
const DATASHEET = "Form responses 1";

function doGet(request) {
  let html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate();
  let htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  htmlOutput.addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1');
  return htmlOutput;
}

function getIndex() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("Index").getContent();
}

//INCLUDE HTML PARTS, EG. JAVASCRIPT, CSS, OTHER HTML FILES
function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
    .getContent();
}

function processFormCreate(formObject) { 
var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('11uGKfy0Jh-24-RI-iIdjGhDtWxwhgiKRHT8JS9guP-Q'); 
var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Form responses 1'); 
  let values = [[
      formObject.districtName,
      formObject.upazilaName,
      formObject.name,
      formObject.email,
      formObject.eiin
    ]];
createRecord(values);    
    } 

function createRecord(values) {
  try {
    let valueRange = Sheets.newRowData();
    valueRange.values = values;

    let appendRequest = Sheets.newAppendCellsRequest();
    appendRequest.sheetId = SPREADSHEETID;
    appendRequest.rows = valueRange;

    Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.append(valueRange, SPREADSHEETID, DATARANGE, { valueInputOption: "RAW" });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Failed with error %s', err.message);
  }
}



I tried with above code, but every time form value is appended to google sheet starting from first Column (A Column), But I want to append form value to google sheet starting from second Column (B Column), Please help me...........

Perhaps that is easier to do through the SpreadsheetApp API. Try this:
function createRecord(values) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREADSHEETID);
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(DATASHEET);
  const range = sheet.getRange(DATARANGE);
  appendRows_(sheet, values, range.getColumn());
}

For that to work, you will need to paste the appendRows_() and getLastRow_() utility functions in your script project. See my appendRows_() post.

Thank you for your better response, I apply your suggestion, but can't work, Please help me, apps script link:  https://script.google.com/u/1/home/projects/15z8-EQAvJWxZSu9LzgUME0MawqpItQi6iTCmPgzWlPTFNpEhs_sCm4MN/edit            Spreadsheet Link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1C8YJgkaTcVHw1BwL__9uZyskk3i9fCFGsgr-wSUwXUI/edit#gid=0

Will it work openById()  instead of getActive() in SpreadsheetApp? Because of this, it seems that it is not being resolved. what do you think? Please help me. I humbly request you to cooperate with me to the end.

A spreadsheet accessed through openById() should work just fine. There is a strange-looking return statement in processFormCreate(). Use console.log() in createRecord() to confirm that it actually gets run.

This question is about "how to append form value to google sheet starting from second column". Please ask only one question per post. Post a new question instead.

Instead of appendRow() you could try setValues().  In which case, you could replace this part of your code:
function processFormCreate(formObject) { 
var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('11uGKfy0Jh-24-RI-iIdjGhDtWxwhgiKRHT8JS9guP-Q'); 
var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Form responses 1'); 
  let values = [[
      formObject.districtName,
      formObject.upazilaName,
      formObject.name,
      formObject.email,
      formObject.eiin
    ]];
createRecord(values);    
    } 

function createRecord(values) {
  try {
    let valueRange = Sheets.newRowData();
    valueRange.values = values;

    let appendRequest = Sheets.newAppendCellsRequest();
    appendRequest.sheetId = SPREADSHEETID;
    appendRequest.rows = valueRange;

    Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.append(valueRange, SPREADSHEETID, DATARANGE, { valueInputOption: "RAW" });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Failed with error %s', err.message);
  }
}

with this:
    function processFormCreate(formObject) { 
var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('11uGKfy0Jh-24-RI-iIdjGhDtWxwhgiKRHT8JS9guP-Q'); 
var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Form responses 1'); 
  let values = [[
      formObject.districtName,
      formObject.upazilaName,
      formObject.name,
      formObject.email,
      formObject.eiin
    ]];
createRecord(values);    
    

function createRecord(values) {
  try {
      ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow()+1,2,1,5).setValues(values);  
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Failed with error %s', err.message);
  }
}
} 


Thank you for your better response, I apply your suggestion, but can't work, Please help me, apps script link: https://script.google.com/u/1/home/projects/15z8-EQAvJWxZSu9LzgUME0MawqpItQi6iTCmPgzWlPTFNpEhs_sCm4MN/edit   Spreadsheet Link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1C8YJgkaTcVHw1BwL__9uZyskk3i9fCFGsgr-wSUwXUI/edit#gid=0

What is the issue you are having?  Are you getting an error?
